# Counting Photoshop Clipping Path Points

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I am trying to make a Javascript script that gives me an alert of how many clipping paths there are in the file and how much anchor points it has. (If the clipping path is too complex InDesign will crash on some computers in our environment)

I found in the Scripting Guide the object PathPoint and PathPointInfo, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What I made so far is this

```
// pathCount 

// enable double clicking from the Macintosh Finder or the Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// in case we double clicked the file
app.bringToFront();

var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;


var totalPathItemCount = activeDoc.pathItems.length;

//myPathItem.subPathItems.length;

var myPathItem = activeDoc.pathItems.getByName("CLIPPING");

var mySubPathItem = myPathItem.subPathItems;

var clippingPathPointCount = myPathItem.pathPoints.length;



alert("There are " + totalPathItemCount + " paths and CLIPPING has " + clippingPathPointCount " points " );
```

Comment: I want to report the total number of anchor points the path "CLIPPING" has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over each `subPathItem` using a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and add the count of anchor points (i.e. for each `subPathItem`) to the `clippingPathTotalAnchorCount` variable. For example:

```js
#target photoshop

app.bringToFront();

var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;
var totalPathItemCount = activeDoc.pathItems.length;

// Specifically for the path named "CLIPPING"...
var myPathItem = activeDoc.pathItems.getByName("CLIPPING");
var mySubPathItems = myPathItem.subPathItems;
var mySubPathItemCount = mySubPathItems.length;

// Loop over each subpath of the path named "CLIPPING".
// The count of anchor points for each subpath are added to the total.
var clippingPathTotalAnchorCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < mySubPathItemCount; i++) {
  clippingPathTotalAnchorCount += mySubPathItems[i].pathPoints.length;
}

alert("The document has " + totalPathItemCount + " path(s).\r" +
    "The path named CLIPPING has " + mySubPathItemCount + " subpaths,\r" +
    "with a total of " + clippingPathTotalAnchorCount + " anchor points.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Index the item in teh collection with [0]
var mySubPathItem = myPathItem.subPathItems[0];
```